# Incorrect bounds in solution to question on pitman estimator in Casella and Berger problem 7.35

Tags: inference

For Casella and Berger problem 7.35, the solution is shown.  For part (c), are the bounds in the integral incorrect, or am I missing something? Here $f(x-\theta)=uniform(\theta-.5,\theta+.5)$.

[image]

Comment: What does that $u$ mean?

Comment: indeed $-1/2$, not $+1/2$